# Problems with Google's OAuth

Tags: oauth, common-lisp, blogger

I had a Lisp application that used the cl-oauth library to contact Google's Blogger API. This worked fine until about a week ago, when suddenly it stopped working, refusing me access to the protected resource, getting errors like this:
 401: Must authenticate to use 'default&#39
when I try to access the protected resource.

The URL that gets this response (generated by cl-oauth) is:

`http://www.blogger.com/feeds/default/blogs?oauth_signature=KEtBmxpM%252FfIgcCjMpiCM9DxNeBs%253D&oauth_consumer_key=wuwei.name&oauth_token=1%252FhXeaTHEe2eumbBCvrjvUvsQhetK3VZ0skk8qy-bpFcc&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1325121590&oauth_nonce=898902330744558861&oauth_version=1.0`

In other words, I can go through the whole authentication process, get an access token, but then the token doesn't work to access the resource.

So, I guess the question is, did Google change anything in the last week or so? Are they phasing out OAuth 1.0 or something?  Any clues appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but the version of cl-oauth in quicklisp stopped working for me for accessing Twitter API some time ago. The fork at http://github.com/arielnetworks/cl-oauth seems to work. I haven't been able to figure out why the quicklisp version stopped working, since the primary difference is that the fork uses authorization through headers rather than url, but computes everything else in the same way as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

in fact the cl-oath was fixed. There was a change in drakma, which wasn't quite backwardly compatible. It did break cl-twitter as the poster Ramarran pointed out but things should be back to normal now

Answer (score 0):

Well, I gave up and wrote my own implementation of OAuth 2.0 (cl-oauth uses 1.0). Much simpler and it works. Code is not quite ready for public view but I will release it eventually.

Comment: What the hell, it's rather simple, so here it is for those interested: https://github.com/mtravers/waybacker/blob/master/src/oauth2-google.lisp

Comment: The above link no longer goes anywhere